# Automatic Ado.Net layer generation tools in .NET applications

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq, ado.net, data-access-layer

I have read some articles about automatic code generation of ADO.Net data access layers in .Net applications. There are some tools available like CodeSmith or LLBLGen Pro. Does anyone has experience with these tools? Is it better to use these tools rather than using LINQ? Thanks.

Comment: "better" is subjective, and depends on a lot of factors. Perhaps the only way to answer that is to see if they do what **you** need. Indeed, your requirements can change between projects, or even at different places in a single project. These things are tools: you are allowed to use more than one tool.

Answer (score 1):

Better is subjective - however, I understand what you're really trying to ask.  Essentially, my answer to the question of which tool is right (best) for the job is: it depends on the job. Linq -> SQL is older tech of which M$ has no plans of updating or improving. I would stay away from it... if you want similar functionality Entity Framework or another ORM is best.

NoSQL is huge right now and offers a big boost in productivity due to no database development or mapping or ORM layer to muck with. Just create your entities and store them!  My recommendations on those are:

RavenDB

CouchBase

MongoDB

Riak

Redis

Cassandra

There are also graph databases useful for 'networks' of 'things' that are related in some fashion or another....  the two that I've used are below:

Neo4j (popular, java based, has .net client)

Sones (.net based - newer kid on the block)

As for SQL databases - well, some companies don't want to endure a paradigm shift or have requirements that stipulate only x database will be used in the company, etc...  In those cases you have to work with whatever you have to work with. ORMs can aid in this arena... Some popular ORMs are listed below:

Entity Framework (M$)

NHibernate (very popular)

Subsonic (older but still used)

Dapper

Massive

PetaPOCO

And as for regular ado.net and to address your main question - there are not a lot of frameworks that generate the data layer for plain ado.net, etc... but I did find these and it turns out to be very useful in my projects:

http://www.elencysolutions.co.uk/   (not open source)

[http://spgen.codeplex.com/](http://spgen.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/patches) (open source & customizable)

http://www.nettiers.com/ (open source but sorta old-erish)